# Global Event Dispatcher

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, events, design-patterns, air

What would be the dissadvantages to using a Global Event Dispatcher, as described here:
http://www.riaspace.com/2010/11/unframework-so-how-to-getaway-without-any-framework/
Bearing in mind, I am working solely on small(ish) applications.

```
// eventDispatcher.as script file

package 
{
    import flash.events.IEventDispatcher;

    public function get eventDispatcher():IEventDispatcher
    {
        return _eventDispatcher;
    }
}

import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
import flash.events.IEventDispatcher;

var _eventDispatcher:IEventDispatcher = new EventDispatcher();
```

---

```
public class MyViewPM
{
    public function btn_clickHandler():void
    {
        eventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(new MyEvent(MyEvent.EVENT_TYPE));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are working on smaller projects and on your own, then a global dispatcher is probably fine and can save you a bit of time.

The problem is with bigger applications and several developers working on the same codebase. My experience is that (less experienced) developers will quickly abuse the global event system and send events over it that should really be local events (mostly view events). This makes the code hard to understand, test and modify since you have little control over who dispatches and who listens for certain events. As with global state, data can get modified in different places at the same time which can lead to debugging nightmares.

If you are interested in an enhanced global dispatcher, check out the [AS3Commons EventBus](http://as3commons.org/as3-commons-eventbus/index.html).

Comment: Good description and it also explains the usual issues with global stuff. People (not only inexperienced developers) tend to abuse it in order to make something work in a stressed situation. Something that despite wishes to remove, still will live on forever. Another thing to mention is that events are a bit slow and error prone when it comes to memory management which is why a lot of people prefer signals or one of its' equivalents.

Comment: Agreed.  Global events are in contrast with OOP best practices for all reasons previously mentioned.  Maintaining spaghetti code that flows like white water is a nightmare.

Comment: Cool, I think it makes a lot of sense for my one off projects to use something like this (easy to add client features at a moments notice at an exhibition for instance). Is it possible to create a class like eventDispatcher.as above, but one that only accepts CustomEvents that extend an abstract class eventDispatcherEvent?

Comment: Sure, you could just add a method dispatchCustomEvent(event:CustomEvent) and hide the internal event dispatcher.